# SignalR and Angular in ASP.NET, client dosen't get response

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I try to add SignalR in angular controller but it dosen't work for me. This my code in angular:

```
var app; 
function () {
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.value('ordersHub', $.connection.ordersHub)
$.connection.hub.start();
app.controller('sendMessage', function ($scope, ordersHub) {
    $scope.messages = [];
    console.log(ordersHub.client)
    ordersHub.client.addNewOrder = function hubMethodInvoked(data) {
        console.log('get response in client');
        $scope.messages.push(data);
    };

    $scope.sendMessage = function () {
        $scope.messages.push($scope.message)
        ordersHub.server.joinGroup("someGroup");
        ordersHub.server.newOrder($scope.message, 1);
    }
});
})();
```

Code from Hub controller in ASP.NET:

```
public class OrdersHub : Hub
{
    public void NewOrder(string groupName, string message)
    {
        Clients.Group(groupName).addNewOrder(message);
    }

    public void JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }
}
```

Method 'sendMessage' from angular controller works fine and send request to ASP.NET controller, the main problem is that client isn't get response from server, look on *ordersHub.client.addNewOrder* in angular.

Thank you in advance for yours reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change

```
ordersHub.server.newOrder($scope.message, 1);
```

to

```
ordersHub.server.newOrder("someGroup", $scope.message);
```